# EJB injected into a task returns UnsatisfiedResolutionException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, inject

I just installed Glassfish 4 and I'm trying to implement a web app that includes a long running thread that continuously inserts entities into a DB, that is started when a servlet is called.
When the EJB managing the entity is injected into the task, I get an UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type:... error in the Instance.get() method.

The EJB

```
@Stateless
public class MeasureEJB {

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;

    @Inject
    Instance<UpdatingTask> myTaskInstance;


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "smarthomePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Measure> findMeasures() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Measure b");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Measure createMeasure (Measure _measure) {
        em.persist(_measure);
        return _measure;
    }

    public void executeBgThread() {
        UpdatingTask myTask = myTaskInstance.get(); <- Here I get the error
        this.managedExecutorService.submit(myTask);
    }
}
```

The servlet

```
@WebServlet(description = "Servlet used to start the historizer", urlPatterns = { "/starthistorizer" })
public class StartHistorizer extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public StartHistorizer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        measureEjb.executeBgThread();

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

and the task

@Stateless
public class UpdatingTask implements Runnable {

```
private static final String TAG = "smarthome";

@EJB
MeasureEJB measureEjb;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        <Insert entities upon sensor messages>
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

and finally the error

```
[2016-09-02T13:19:17.419+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1472822357419] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.StartHistorizer]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.StartHistorizer threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy244.executeBgThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.__EJB31_Generated__MeasureEJB__Intf____Bean__.executeBgThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.StartHistorizer.doGet(StartHistorizer.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type: class com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.UpdatingTask; Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:101)
    at com.storassa.javaee.smarthome.MeasureEJB.executeBgThread(MeasureEJB.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 34 more
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `@LocalBean` annotation to `UpdatingTask`

Your Session Bean implements an interface, that means it is only available with that interface in cdi. With `@LocalBean`it is also available with the classes name.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normally possible to execute EJBs in randomly created threads. This is because they expect to find contextual information such as security and transaction management to be associated with the currently executing thread.

Additionally, it is never a good idea to create unmanaged threads in an enterprise application because you have no way of controlling this use of resources.

The way around this is to make use of Java EE 7's Concurrency Utilities which provides mechanisms for acquiring properly prepared threads from a thread pool that you have configured in your server.

You can read more about this at [Java EE 7: Using Concurrency Utilities in Asynchronous Servlets](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/concurrency/Concurrency.html).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm pretty new to these topics, so I have to study a little more about concurrency in JavaEE

Comment: I eventually found out that your answer was the correct one, as the previous one only removed the error, but data were not stored in the DB. I followed the correct way to manage threads in JavaEE as described in the link you referenced and everything now works. +1